# How to append a string to int/float dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my original dataframe:

```
  >>> df
           c0      c1      c2        c3   c4   c5   c6  c7     c8
    0  key0:j  key1:z  key2:b  key3:bsy  afj  upz  343  13  ruhwd
    1  key0:u  key1:i  key2:a  key3:dvp  ibt  dxv  154   0  adsif
    2  key0:t  key1:a  key2:a  key3:jqj  dtd  yxq  540  49  kxthz
    3  key0:j  key1:z  key2:b  key3:bsy  afj  upz  322  13  ruhwd
    4  key0:j  key1:z  key2:b  key3:bsy  afj  upz  397  13  ruhwd
    5  key0:u  key1:i  key2:a  key3:dvp  ibt  dxv  110   0  adsif
    6  key0:t  key1:a  key2:a  key3:jqj  dtd  yxq  526  49  kxthz
    7  key0:t  key1:u  key2:g  key3:nfk  ekh  trc   85  83  xppnl
```

I am calculating sum of c6 for c0 in pandas using this:

```
df.groupby(['c0'])['c6'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       c0     0
0  key0:j  1062
1  key0:t  1151
2  key0:u   264
```

Here, I want the output of the groupby in such a way, that the column with sum should also have a string 'abc' attached to it. Like below:

```
    c0        0
0  key0:j     abc1062
1  key0:t     abc1151
2  key0:u     abc264
```

I went through a lot of posts, and could not get the desired answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean prepend, right?

Comment: Do you need `"abc"1062` or just `abc1062`?

Comment: @Anton Protopopov
I need just abc1062

Comment: @pp_ : Yes, I mean prepend

Comment: @MayankPorwal could you attach your original dataframe before grouping?

Comment: I thinkg something like that should work: `df.groupby(['c0'])['c6'].sum().apply(lambda x: 'abc' + x.astype(str)).reset_index()`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov
I've added original dataframe and edited my post.

Comment: @MayankPorwal check my comment above

Comment: @AntonProtopopov
That works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `apply` `lambda` after grouping before `reset_index`:

```
In [19]: df.groupby(['c0'])['c6'].sum().apply(lambda x: 'abc' + x.astype(str)).reset_index()
Out[19]:
       c0       c6
0  key0:j  abc1062
1  key0:t  abc1151
2  key0:u   abc264
```

Or you could use groupby `as_index` argument and then check for your col name `c6`:

```
In [29]: df.groupby(['c0'], as_index=False)['c6'].sum().apply(lambda x: 'abc' + x.astype(str) if x.name=='c6' else x)
Out[29]:
       c0       c6
0  key0:j  abc1062
1  key0:t  abc1151
2  key0:u   abc264
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) for selecting second column and convert `int` column to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print df
       c0     0
0  key0:j  1062
1  key0:t  1151
2  key0:u   264

df.ix[:,1] = '"abc"' + df.ix[:,1].astype(str)
print df
       c0          0
0  key0:j  "abc"1062
1  key0:t  "abc"1151
2  key0:u   "abc"264
```

Or:

```
df.ix[:,1] = 'abc' + df.ix[:,1].astype(str)
print df
       c0        0
0  key0:j  abc1062
1  key0:t  abc1151
2  key0:u   abc264
```

If columns are `a` and `b`:

```
print df
        a     b
0  key0:j  1062
1  key0:t  1151
2  key0:u   264

df['b'] = 'abc' + df['b'].astype(str)
print df
        a        b
0  key0:j  abc1062
1  key0:t  abc1151
2  key0:u   abc264
```

EDIT:

You can try, but I think it is slower as solution above:

```
df = df.groupby(['c0'])['c6'].apply(lambda x: 'abc' + str( x.sum())).reset_index()
print df
       c0       c6
0  key0:j  abc1062
1  key0:t  abc1151
2  key0:u   abc264
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael
the column with numerical values 1062,1151,264 is basically the output of the groupby command. So, what I want is, at the time when groupby is calculating result, it should also append string abc to the sum.